# Gaussian calculation error when optimizing an enzyme bound with a metal ion?

Tags: gaussian, optimization

I want to optimize an enzyme with a metal ion bound to the active site of the enzyme.
Using PyMOL software I placed the metal ion in the active site of the enzyme and the metal-enzyme structure was used for the optimization using gaussian 09.
I tried to optimize the structure in the ground state with DFT (B3LYP) method and 6-31G (d) basis set.

When I start the optimization, first get an out-of-memory error and I continue the optimization with the suggestion given `Use %mem=1050MW` to provide the minimum amount of memory required to complete this step.
However, the next problem is the process terminates without mentioning the error specifically.
The final lines printed in the process are

```
 H(PDBName=1H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=486_A) 0    -15.62485  -15.07272  -38.775   L 
 H(PDBName=2H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=486_A) 0    -15.71863  -16.63759  -38.775   L 
 H(PDBName=1H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=487_A) 0    -28.25085  -22.36872  -12.833   L 
 H(PDBName=2H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=487_A) 0    -28.34463  -23.93359  -12.833   L 
 H(PDBName=1H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=488_A) 0    -31.65985  -20.74372  -10.48    L 
 H(PDBName=2H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=488_A) 0    -31.75363  -22.30859  -10.48    L 
 H(PDBName=1H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=489_A) 0    -30.88785  -21.47372  -13.087   L 
 H(PDBName=2H,ResName=HOH,ResNum=489_A) 0    -30.98163  -23.03859  -13.087   L
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but please provide an input file if you want this question to remain open.